# Assigning a variable inside if loop : Windows Bat script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, delayedvariableexpansion

I'm trying to write a bat script and faced the following issue.

Below is the snippet with which the issue is dealt with.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
@echo off
@echo:
echo Select an option:
echo *****************
@echo:
echo 1) process 2gen files
@echo:
echo 2) process 3gen files
@echo:
set /p option=Enter option number : %=%

set fileName=nil
echo %option%
if %option% == 1 (
set fileName = 2gen
echo !fileName!
)
echo !fileName!
```

The output of this bat script is as follows:

```
Select an option:
*****************

1) process 2gen files

2) process 3gen files

Enter option number : 1
1
nil
nil
```

i'm expecting the echo for fileName to have value `2gen` but it is still printing `nil`

In my first attempt, i didn't use the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions` and `!fileName!` (instead used `%fileName%`)

After searching for solution enabled the delayed expansion. But still couldn't get what the exact mistake is.

Also the OS version being used is `Windows 7 64 bit`

Please help me in pointing out the mistake.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set fileName = 2gen` sets a variable named `filename<space>` to a value `<space>2gen`. Get rid of the spaces. Even better, use this recommended syntax:

```
set "variable=value"
```

to avoid unintended trailing spaces.

(of course you *could* use `echo !filename !`...)